# behavior of initial form state of touched was false

Tags: angular

what was the actual behavior of `touched` property of a form.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khvoay?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

If you check above link, In console you could see `touched` property as `false` for initial changes/touch. can any one provide theory why it behaves like that.

Comment: it becomes touched once you blur from the input at least once. That is all

Comment: Yea, is there any theory why it behaves like that?

Comment: This property is mainly done to hide error for the field, when user haven't still interacted with input. So for most of inputs the most logical "touched", "time to show error" state is after the first blur

Answer (score 0):

Touched attr is changed when the user interact with the input. if you add values from your code is not considered as "touched"